# C++ easiest keyboard input

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

What is the simplest way to get keyboard input from the user? Not where you have to hit enter in the console to input data. I have found no tutorials on this and i need help. I only know how to create console applications right now. I use the minGW compiler and Im usig windows 7. So, basically, is there already a library for keyboard input and how do I use it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you can use the `_kbhit()` function from `conio.h` to determine whether a keypress is available.  This is useful if you don't want calls to `getch()` to block when there is no user input.

Using `_kbhit()` allows you to do other processing while waiting for keyboard input.  But you might just want to wait.

```
int GetKeypress()
{
    while( !_kbhit() ) Sleep(25);
    return getch();
}
```

For a more generic solution you could look at the `ncurses` library.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested edit to my post, Harrison.  However, it was invalid.  The function does not let you do other processing "at the same time" as waiting for input.  To do that, you would use another thread.  The function simply lets you 'peek' at the input buffer to see if characters are waiting.  That way you avoid making a potentially blocking call when you don't want to block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short demo of what's probably the simplest way:

```
#include <conio.h>

int main(){ 
    int ch = getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I would have to keep calling that over and over so it can be changed.

Comment: Yes -- each time you call it, it'll read one key stroke (other than things like shift, control, and alt).